# インストール済みのpythonコマンドが認識されない

Tags: python, windows, cmd

書籍「スラスラわかるPython」で勉強をしているのですがフォルダ指定をしたあと、`python`と打っていこうとしたのですがコマンドとして理解してくれません。

```
PS C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\surasura-python\chapter01> python height-average.py
python : 用語 'python' は、コマンドレット、関数、スクリプト ファイル、または操作可能なプログラムの名前として認識されません。名前が正しく記述されていることを確認し、パスが含まれている場合はそのパスが正しいことを確認してから、再試行してください。
発生場所 行:1 文字:1
+ python height-average.py
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

初心者すぎて質問内容が乏しく本当に申し訳ないのですが何かご教授いただければと思い質問させていただきました。他に聞く人もいなく…。図々しいですがご協力宜しくお願い致します。

**3/6追記**（この時間しか勉強ができないので反応が遅くなりすみません。）
Windows10　64bitを使用
python-3.6.4をインストール（Add Python 3.6 to PATHも一緒にインストール）
エディタはVisual Studio CodeでPythonプラグインを追加しました。

Windows PowerShellではPythonはうごきました。
Visual Studio Codeでフォルダを作成後、
テキストファイルに記載しての統合ターミナルで実行しようとしたところ
上記のようなエラーが表示されました。

他なにか必要な情報がありましたらコメントいただけると嬉しいです。

Comment: 「スラスラわかるPython」を持ってない人には回答しづらいと感じました。できるだけ省略せずにこれまでに行ってきたこと、お使いの環境を質問に追記していただけますか？

Comment: インストールはどのように行いましたか？
環境変数の設定がなされていないような気が…

他の方も書かれていますがより詳細に書いていただければより詳しいアドバイスが貰えると思います。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。確かに答えづらい内容ですね…。詳細記載します。

Comment: もしかして、 "python" でなく、"py" とすると動くとか?　Visual stdio 2017でインストールしたら、そうなりました。 単に環境設定の問題でしたが、原因がわかるまでに苦労しました。 (VS のプラグインは、パスを追加しなかった!)　... 今、確認したところ、VS Codeの環境設定に、 "python.pythonPath": "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3" が入っています。 (Pythonは、Anaconda3 としてインストール)

Comment: アドバイスくださり、ありがとうございました。また、原因が単純なもので申し訳なさがいっぱいです。すみませんでした。コツコツ努力していきますので引き続きお力添えいただければ幸いです…。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ご覧になっている書籍「スラスラわかるPython」でPythonのインストールと設定について以下の章で触れられています(出版社のwebサイトで公開されている[立ち読み](http://www.shoeisha.co.jp/book/preview/9784798151090)でも内容を確認できます)。

**第1章 1_2 Pythonのインストール・環境設定**

必要な作業としては、

1. [Pythonの公式サイト](https://www.python.org/)からインストーラの入手(書籍では3.6.x)。
2. インストール途中で「**Add Python 3.6 to PATH**」 にチェックを入れる。
3. インストール後、PowerShellを起動したら`python -V`と入力して環境が整ったかの確認。

をもう一度よく確認してみてください。ありがちなのは二番目のPATHの追加を忘れているのが原因じゃないかと思います。

---

Pythonのインストール直後は(**Add Python to PATH**にチェックを入れていても)環境変数に設定が反映されていない可能性があるので、いったんWindowsを再起動してから再度確認してください。

環境変数PATHにPythonのインストール先が追加されているかは、PowerShellを開いて`$env:Path.split(";")`を実行します。実行結果の一覧にPythonのパスが含まれているかを確認します。
(以下の例では説明のため敢えてPythoのPATHを削除して実行しています)

```
PS C:\Users\cubick> $env:Path.split(";")
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Program Files\WinMerge
C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin
C:\Users\cubick\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

PS C:\Users\tatsuya> python -V
python : 用語 'python' は、コマンドレット、関数、スクリプト ファイル、または操作可能なプログラムの名前として認識されません。
(以下略...)
```

もし一覧にPythonのパスが含まれていない場合には、手動で環境変数の設定を行ってください。

- Windowsのスタートボタン→設定(歯車アイコン)→検索窓に「システム環境変数の編集」と入力して表示された項目をクリック
- システムのプロパティ→「詳細設定」タブ→環境変数をクリック
- システム環境変数の「Path」を選択して編集→新規をクリックして「C:\Python36」など実際のインストールフォルダを入力
- 設定が完了したらいったんWindowsを再起動後、Pythonの動作確認

Comment: わかりやすい質問内容にしていただいてありがとうございました。大変助かりました…python-3.6.4をインストールし、Add Python 3.6 to PATHにもチェックを入れました。質問内容に環境を記載しますのでお手数ですがご確認いただければと思います。

Comment: 完全に再起動が原因だったようです…。家族共有のPCで作業しているもので再起動せずに使い続けていました…。再起動後、通常に動作することを確認できました。ご迷惑をおかけしてしまいすみませんでした。とても助かりました。ありがとうございます。今後も勉強にはげみます。

Answer (score -4):

python -version
python3 -versionでバージョン確認できず困っておりました。

pyだけでバージョンの確認できました（ver3.7）